# Why did this question get closed as a "third party resource request"?

Tags: discussion

As far as I understand this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342553/where-reliably-store-a-million-events-per-second), the OP is not asking *literally* where to store the event data, or which tool or database to use for, but **how** to do this. And that is obviously a conceptual question, which is IMHO within in the site's scope. Ok, the question misses to tell us what the OP already has tried or found so far, and some background about the environment he uses, but I guess this does not make the question so bad it deserves a closing for an IMHO wrong reason and without any comment.

Comment: discussion related to matter of immediate closing: [How soon should I “vote to close”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/165773)

Comment: @gnat: thanks, I edited my question and removed the word "immediately" to make my point more clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with [amon's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8460/4). The closure was valid, but the close reason was wrong. It gives the wrong idea about what needs to happen to fix the question. I fixed the close reason.

Answer (score 5):

I generally agree with the close votes. It is likely many answers would consist of irrelevant tech recommendations that are also quite possibly wrong. “I would use this NoSQL database”, “Google uses $x”, ….

But we should judge the question, not hypothetical answers.

That still leads a rather broad, open-ended question. Real questions have answers. What is the correct answer to “What options do I have”? There isn't the one correct architecture for high-throughput event storage. If there are dozens of possible answers and each is “correct”, the question is too broad.

To me, it seems like OP needs a *discussion* about their requirements. In that case, OP doesn't need a question-and-answer site, they need a colleague or consultant. In particular, they have provided many vague non-functional requirements for their system, but we lack all their context.

I think this question could perhaps be made suitable if the question would be about a concrete architecture, data structure, or design that OP is using to tackle their problems. But in its current form, I'm not going to vote for reopen.

Comment: Ok, in the current form the question may probably be too broad, but it seems the OP has a very real scenario in mind, so should we not ask him for more specific information instead of closing this **as a third party-resource request**, **without any comment** ? Some people here seem to be very trigger-happy with the close button.

Comment: @DocBrown I've written down my views on this for [Should we kindly explain the basic stuff, or rudely close the question?](/a/8375): “When a question is put “on hold”, that is not necessarily rude. It is an opportunity to improve and then reopen the question. […] Our close reasons try to explain why [it] isn't a good fit […]. As such, votes are a great low-effort way to […] give feedback to the OP. […] Unfortunately, editing questions, engaging in a discussion with OP […] requires substantial effort. I am not required to expend that effort, […]. So I personally tend to vote and move along.”

Comment: I agree to this - as long as the close reason gives an understandable explanation why the question got closed, which was IMHO not the case here. But thanks to Thomas, he fixed it.